# How would you pass an If statement WHEN 2 coordinate arrays are within a range of 10 of each other?

Tags: python, arrays

I am using Pygame for a programming class and need to recreate a game of tag. I am attempting to pass an if statement when the coordinates of the tagger are within a range of 10 of the player's coordinates. I attempted using 'in range()' within the if statement but it didn't seem to work. Not sure what I was doing wrong.

```
if (pos[0] == enemypos[0] & pos[1] == enemypos[1]):

    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)

    gameovertext = font.render("You're IT", True, WHITE)

    screen.blit(gameovertext, [x_mouse+10, y_mouse+10])
```

Answer (score 1):

Subtract them to get the difference in position, rather than checking equality:

```
if abs(pos[0] - enempypos[0]) < 10 and abs(pos[1] - enempypos[1]) < 10:
```

You can also compute the [Euclidean distance](http://description:.%5B3%5D).

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you subtract the two sets of coordinates from each other, then you will get the difference between them.
This value could be negative, so you would also need to use `abs()`

```py
if (abs(pos[0] - enemypos[0]) < 10 and abs(pos[1] - enemypos[1]) < 10:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dist` function in the standard math library to caculate the euclidean distance.

```
import dist from math

if dist(pos, enemypos) >= 10:
  # in range
```